# jQuery fadeIn CSS class

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, fadein

I'm trying to do simple fadeIn() CSS class on certain objects that have the "button" class. I want to fadeIn the "hoverbutton" class on hover and then fadeOut when their mouse leaves the item.

I found this in the questions. It seemed to work well until i noticed when i hover over multiple buttons quickly some get stuck on the "hoverbutton" class. Not a clue how to fix that. Any suggestions would be great.

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hoverbutton', 200);
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hoverbutton', 200);
});
```

it seems they get stuck when i hover over one and quickly jump to another item with that class **before** the fading on the first one is complete.

stop()ing produced the same result. hover class still gets stuck

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
  $(this).stop().addClass('hoverbutton', 200);
}, function(){
  $(this).stop().removeClass('hoverbutton', 200);
});
```

Comment: I don't think `, 200` is a valid argument for `removeClass` and `addClass`

Comment: @kei - jQueryUI adds the duration to `addClass` and `removeClass`: http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because jQueryUI is using the `style` property to do the animation, and if it doesn't complete (because the hover-out occurs before hover-in finishes) the class it's animating to isn't actually added, and so can't be removed by the hover-out.

To fix this, we need to do two things on the hover-out:

- stop the `addClass()` animation
- remove any temporary style created by the `addClass()` animation

Like so..

```
$('.button').hover(function() {
    $(this)
        .addClass('hoverbutton', 200);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop()
        .attr("style", "")
        .removeClass('hoverbutton', 200);
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/RBTT8/

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the animation queue:

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().addClass('hoverbutton', 200);
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().removeClass('hoverbutton', 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). You would add it to your call like so:

```
$('.button').hover(function(){
  $(this).stop().addClass('hoverbutton', 200);
}, function(){
  $(this).stop().removeClass('hoverbutton', 200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to achieve the same effect would be to use [CSS3 Transitions](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions), supported in everything ***except Internet Explorer*** (up to version 10).

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3yr8G/

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS add --

```
    ex)--styles take 0.5s to appear        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

to the element u need to fade in

w3schools transition link:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp